# pass java object from javascript to java

Tags: java, javascript, mirth

Is it possible to pass objects created in Javascript to java?

for example I have a POJO called myPojo with propertys name and address

The object is created in Javascript:

```
var myPojo = new Packages.CreatePOJO();

myPojo.setName("Alpha");
```

Then I pass it to a java function

var replacer = new Packages.VelocityReplace();
replacer.replace("a template", myPojo);

The replacer class is this.

public class VelocityReplace {
    public static String replace(String templateStr, Object in) 
        throws Exception
    { ... }

The exception generated is:

Wrapped java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject cannot be cast to CreatePOJO

I am using Mirth Connect which is a real time interfacing engine that is providing & pushing the data to the myPojo object.  It uses javascript for scripting, this is why I need to push the data from javascript to java.

Comment: Is your Java running in an applet on your page?  Or is it on your web server?

Comment: It's on the server, it's not a web server but an interface server, but the data handoff is similar I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON, probably. I'm assuming you don't want to pass functions as part of your object from JS to Java. Java JSON libraries include GSON, Jackson and others.

Comment: So basically use to toJSON() function within javascript on the java variable to convert it to JSON, then pass it to Java, then convert it back to the original object using fromJSON from within my called Java function?

Comment: This works.  In javascript do this:   var gson = new Packages.com.google.gson.Gson();
 var JSONstr = gson.toJson(myPojo);

In java do this:       Gson gson = new Gson();
     POJO myPOJO = gson.fromJson(in, POJO.class);